# How can I get only the value entered by the user in numGames() and avoid the program from printing "What's your name?" again?

Tags: java

I want the game() method to print out only the name retrived from the name() method. How can I do that? If I just put the name() method it will ask What's your name again instead of just printing the name given by the user

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        name(keyboard);
        numGames(keyboard);
        game(computerPlayer, keyboard);

        

    // asks the users for their name
    public static String name(Scanner keyboard) {
        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        String userName = keyboard.nextLine();
        return userName;

    public static String game(RandomPlayer computerPlayer, Scanner keyboard) {
        int userWins = 0;
        int compWins = 0;
        int userChoice = 0;
        String cpuWon = "The computer won!";
        int cpuChoice = computerPlayer.getComputerChoice();

        String youWon = "Congrats" + name(keyboard) + ", you won!";
        String draw = "The match ended in a draw :(";
        for (int game = 1; game <= numGames(keyboard); game++) {
            System.out.print("Choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper or 3 for scissors. ");
            int decision = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code ?

Comment: And hint: you might need a different kind of loop. You dont know the number of rounds up front. And then, yes: methods returning a value is only half the thing. You ignore the returned result ... and hint: dont post **parts** of your code. Instead give us a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You should store name in a variable and pass it to game!

```
playerName = name(keyboard);
numGames(keyboard);
game(computerPlayer, keyboard, playerName);
```

Or you can store name in the current instance:

```
String this.name;
this.name = name(keyboard);
```

And you will be able to call it in your method game with this.name